# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 Firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to load an image from Firebase Firestore in a Flutter app, but I am getting the following error message:

RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
,

`model.thumbnailUrl[0]` is where the error is coming

Here is the relevant code for the CategoryProductCard class where I'm trying to display the image:

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:user/Config/method.dart';
    import 'package:user/model/item.dart';
    import 'package:user/screens/product_page.dart';
    import 'package:user/widgets/customTextWidget.dart';

    class CategoryProductCard extends StatelessWidget {
      final ItemModel model;

      CategoryProductCard({this.model});
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // double discount1 = ((model.mrp.toDouble() - model.price.toDouble()) /
        //         model.mrp.toDouble()) *
        //     100.0;
        // int discount = discount1.toInt().ceil();
        final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, top: 0),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[100],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                      height: 250,
                      width: size.width * .48,
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (_) => ProductPage(itemModel: model));
                          Navigator.push(context, route);
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(5)),
                              child: Image.network(
                                model.thumbnailUrl[0],
                                height: 150,
                                width: size.width * .48,
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 5.0, right: 5, top: 8),
                                  child: Text(
                                    model.title,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  // child: CustomText(
                                  //   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  //   text: model.title,
                                  //   size: 15,
                                  //   fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  // ),
                                ),
                                // RichText(
                                //   text: new TextSpan(
                                //     children: <TextSpan>[
                                //       new TextSpan(
                                //         text: 'MRP: ₹${model.price}',
                                //         style: new TextStyle(
                                //           color: Colors.grey[500],
                                //           fontSize: 12,
                                //           decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                //         ),
                                //       ),
                                //     ],
                                //   ),
                                // ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                                  child: RichText(
                                    text: new TextSpan(
                                      children: <TextSpan>[
                                        new TextSpan(
                                          text: 'MRP: ₹${model.mrp}',
                                          style: new TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey[500],
                                            fontSize: 11,
                                            decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                RichText(
                                  text: new TextSpan(
                                    children: <TextSpan>[
                                      new TextSpan(
                                        text: 'Price: ',
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                          color: Colors.black87,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      new TextSpan(
                                        text: '₹ ${model.price}',
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // Padding(
                                //     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, top: 0),
                                //     child: CustomText(
                                //       overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                //       text: model.longDescription,
                                //       size: 12,
                                //     )),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 12,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),

                            // Padding(
                            //   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                            //   child: Row(
                            //     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            //     children: [
                            //       CustomText(
                            //         text: '₹' + (model.price).toString(),
                            //         color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            //         size: 14,
                            //         fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            //       ),
                            //       Container(
                            //         alignment: Alignment.center,
                            //         height: 20,
                            //         width: 60,
                            //         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            //             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            //             color: Colors.red.withOpacity(.1)),
                            //         child: CustomText(
                            //           text: '₹' +
                            //               (model.discount).toString() +
                            //               ' Off',
                            //           color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            //           size: 12,
                            //           fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            //         ),
                            //       ),
                            //     ],
                            //   ),
                            // )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 10,
                      right: 10,
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 35,
                        width: 35,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.65)),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            CustomText(
                              text: '${model.discount}%',
                              size: 10,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            CustomText(
                              text: 'OFF',
                              size: 10,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Here is how i passed the model to the above code from different page

```
GridView.builder(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                childAspectRatio: .69),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              ItemModel model;
              if (dataSnapshot.hasData)
                model = ItemModel.fromJson(
                    dataSnapshot.data.docs[index].data());
              //debugPrint(dataSnapshot.data.documents.length.toString());
              if (dataSnapshot.hasData)
                return CategoryProductCard(
                  model: model,
                  
                );
                
              else
                return Text('No more products');
            },
            itemCount:
                dataSnapshot != null ? dataSnapshot.data.docs.length : 0,
          );
```

[This is my data collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CMn3.png)

```
      import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

  class ItemModel {
    String category;
    String details;
    int discount;
    bool isFeatured;
    String longDescription;
    int mrp;
    String pid;
    int price;
    Timestamp publishedDate;
    int quantity;
    String shortInfo;
    String status;
    List thumbnailUrl;
    String title;

    ItemModel({
      this.title,
      this.shortInfo,
      this.publishedDate,
      this.thumbnailUrl,
      this.longDescription,
      this.status,
    });

    ItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      category = json['category'];
      details = json['details'];
      discount = json['discount'];
      isFeatured=json['isFeatured'];
      longDescription = json['longDescription'];
      mrp = json['mrp'];
      pid = json['pid'];
      price = json['price'];
      publishedDate = json['publishedDate'];
      quantity = int.parse(json['quantity']);
      shortInfo = json['shortInfo'];
      status = json['status'];
      thumbnailUrl = json['thumbnailUrl'];
      title = json['title'];
      
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
      final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
      data['title'] = this.title;
      data['shortInfo'] = this.shortInfo;
      data['price'] = this.price;
      if (this.publishedDate != null) {
        data['publishedDate'] = this.publishedDate;
      }
      data['thumbnailUrl'] = this.thumbnailUrl;
      data['longDescription'] = this.longDescription;
      data['status'] = this.status;
      data['details'] = this.details;
      return data;
    }
  }

  class PublishedDate {
    String date;

    PublishedDate({this.date});

    PublishedDate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      date = json['$date'];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
      final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
      data['$date'] = this.date;
      return data;
    }
  }
```

Model giving all the deatils except thumbUrl , Don't know why this is happening , Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `ItemModel` class

Comment: there is no data on `model.thumbnailUrl`

Comment: Is that type `List<String>`?

Comment: @ItemModel class is already added

Comment: thumbnailUrl List is clearly empty here and then you're trying to use it's 1st value which doesn't exits. try printing thumbnailUrl in build.

Comment: Yes @AlexSunderSingh it is List<String>

Comment: It is showing null but @jay same model is giving all the other attributes except this thumbUrl

Comment: Can you add your data collection

Comment: @AshmitSingh then there a problem where you're getting data from firebase. check if thumbnailUrl key spelling in firebase collection and in code where your converting map object from firebase to your model.

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh I have added the data collection

Comment: add fromJson method too.

Comment: I  have that added now  check

Comment: Looks some of the products has empty `thumbnailUrl`

Answer (score 0):

That because `thumbnailUrl` is empty not valued yet.
You have to wait the `Future` that set the values on `thumbnailUrl` then `setState` to refresh the `Widget`.

However to avoid the error you can do something like that:

```
children: [
        model.thumbnailUrl.length > 0 ? 
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(5), topRight: Radius.circular(5)),
            child: Image.network(
              model.thumbnailUrl[0],
              height: 150,
              width: size.width * .48,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ) : CircularProgressIndicator() ,
        //.other widgets here
      ]
```